# Setting Hotkeys for Context Menu in Firefox Addon SDK

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm creating small plugin for a navigation list which will come in the right click context menu.

I want to set up short-cut key for my links.

What i implement is https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/context-menu.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [hotkeys](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/hotkeys.html) module to do just that -- the context-menu and hotkeys just need to read from the same dataset, they don't have to interact with each other.